# store does not have valid reducer when trying to create multiple states in React Toolkit

Tags: reactjs, redux-toolkit

In my slice.js file, I have my slices:

```
import {createSlice} from "@reduxjs/toolkit";
import { combineReducers } from "@reduxjs/toolkit";

export const counterSlice = createSlice({
    name:"trigger",
    initialState:{
        trigger:false
    },

    reducers:{
        flip: (state) =>{
            state.trigger = !state.trigger;
        },

    }

})

export const projectNameSlice = createSlice({
    name:"setName",
    initialState:{
        name: "project"
    },

    reducers:{
        setName: (state, action) =>{
            state.name = action.payload;
        }
    }
})

export const {flip} = counterSlice.actions;
export const {setName} = projectNameSlice.actions;

export default combineReducers({
    counterSlice:counterSlice.reducer,
    projectNameSlice: projectNameSlice.reducer
})
```

At the bottom, I used the combineReducer to export multiple slices, and in my store.js I have the following code:

```
import { configureStore } from "@reduxjs/toolkit";
import {counterSlice, projectNameSlice} from "./trigger";

export default configureStore({
    reducer:{
        trigger: counterSlice,
        projectName:projectNameSlice
        
    },
})
```

When I try to deconstruct the values of either reducers like this:

```
const {trigger} = useSelector((state) => state.trigger);
```

```
  const {myProj} = useSelector((state) => state.projectName);
```

I get the following error:

Store does not have a valid reducer. Make sure the argument passed to combineReducers is an object whose values are reducers.

When I export only one reducer, it works fine, but when I add the second I get this error, I looked at threads of other people getting the same error, but the cause/solution in their case did not work for me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need that `combineReducers` call, but you cannot put your slices into `configureStore`, but you have to put the slice reducers in:

```js
import { configureStore } from "@reduxjs/toolkit";
import {counterSlice, projectNameSlice} from "./trigger";

export default configureStore({
    reducer:{
        trigger: counterSlice.reducer,
        projectName:projectNameSlice.reducer,
    },
})
```

Answer (score -1):

I think this is what you want

```
export default configureStore({
    reducer: combineReducers({
           trigger: counterSlice,
           projectName: projectNameSlice,
    })
})
```

https://redux.js.org/api/combinereducers

Comment: No, this will give me an error:  "reducer" is a required argument,

Comment: My bad I was wrong sorry, i'll edit my code, tell me if it is better